# is there a way to reset a stacking context in css?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm having a hard time getting right stacking order. Is there a physical way to render this right (.above-mask being, well, above mask, while .below-mask stays below) without changing html?
EDIT: Removing z-index on .below-mask is, unfortunately, also impossible.

HTML:

```
<div class="mask"></div>
<div class="below-mask">
  <div class="above-mask"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mask{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  z-index: 10;
}

.below-mask{
  position: absolute;
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

.above-mask{
  position: absolute;
  width: 10em; height: 10em;
  top: 2.5em; left: 2.5em;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrXbaL

EDIT: [How it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0O4r.png) - I'm making a first-steps view. I wanted elements that need to be explained to be above the mask (here it would be the search panel), while everything else stays neatly hidden below.

Comment: I want .below-mask to stay under .mask element, while .above-mask would be above .mask. Right now both of them are under the .mask element, due to how stacking context works.

Comment: Do you want .mask in-between .below-mask and .above-mask?

Comment: Exactly. Withouth changing html markup and removing z-index from the blue element.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot this requirement... Is removing `position: absolute` or forcing `.below-mask.below-mask { position: static }` OK then? :p Example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxwqaK?editors=110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm stupid. I don't need a mask, I can just use eiter a huge box shadow or an outline:

```
outline: 1000em solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
```

It does the trick.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJeNVg

Comment: It's OK to accept your own answer to a question too, so tick away :)

Comment: I need to wait two days to tick it :c